# Android Sql or XML storage question

Tags: android, sqlite

I have about 100 xml files on my sd card
the xml files each contain about 30 elements each and are 5KB each in size.

I do not need to run any complex queries (1 element in the xml file is a link to another xml file is about as complex as it gets)

I am an android newbie and have a steep learning curve ahead so was hoping to leave learning the sqlite until later.

My plan was to read each file into a DOM and just get the elements as needed (will only ever need 1 file at a time and 1 DOM instance at a time).

A cunning plan yes/no? Do you know if there any advantages in this scenario to putting the xml into an sqllite database ?

If you have any thoughts please reply
Thanks
Ste

Comment: Give more some more details about the data and how it relates, this really sound like you should just use SQL DB and forget about XML. You could have the DB in the SD card if youd like.

Answer (score 0):

XML is heavy for parsing, consider using stream format like JSON or put it into an sql DB, XML needs to go trough a DOM parser and parsing needs a lot of CPU.